# Remove particular table from being replicated in a Multi-Master replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, multi-master

I have followed all the steps in [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication) to set-up MySQL Master-Master replication for two database servers.

The master-master replication works fine.

Here is my `my.cnf` file, which contains some additional configuration than that present in the above link for auto-increment:

```
server-id = 1
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 10
auto-increment-offset = 1

log_bin = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log"
binlog_do_db = my_employee_database

log-slave-updates

expire_logs_days = 20

binlog_format = mixed
```

Similarly this is set-up in the other node with some changes.

`my_employee_database` has 4 tables:

1. `my_employee`
2. `my_company`
3. `my_address`
4. `my_audit`.

**Question**

Is there a way I can ignore or stop or remove the table `my_audit` from being replicated among the two server nodes and have the replication run normally for the other 3 tables as it is?

**Environment**

Database: MySQL 5.6.25
OS: CentOS 6.5 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, simply add replicate-ignore-table in your my.cnf . please refer following link for mysql documentation :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-ignore-table

Comment: You will have to restart mysql for the changes in my.cnf to take into effect. In MySQL 5.7 replication-filter variables are dynamic.